# Cucumber tests Execution time is always 0ms after IntelliJ IDEA update

Tags: java, intellij-idea, selenium

I have recently updated IntelliJ IDEA to 2019.1.3 (Community Edition) and execution time for all Cucumber tests appears as 0ms, although the total time execution counter, which is shown separately from the Steps execution window, 
[shows the value without problems](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KPUPo.png).
This may have something to do with other libraries not working well with the new version, but maybe there's a quick fix, before they roll out an update?